# Exponentiation of a $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, matrix-calculus

We know:

$$\exp(At)=I+ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{A^nt^n}{n!}$$

Here $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -w^2 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$  is a $2\times 2$ matrix, 
$I$ is identity matrix.

How to show:
$$\exp(At)=I\cos(wt) + A \sin(wt)/w$$

Comment: You want to diagonalize $A$.

Comment: For a reference, this is called the Rodriguez rotation formula. The cleanest derivation I've seen is from Omnom$\dots$nom's method.

Comment: @JessicaK you missed a nom :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to solve this by diagonalization.  Here's another option:

Note that
$$
A^2 = -w^2I
$$
Thus, we have
$$
A^n = 
\begin{cases}
(-1)^{n/2}w^{n}I& n \text{ is even}\\
(-1)^{(n-1)/2}w^{n-1}A& n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, expand the matrix exponential
$$
\exp(At)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{A^nt^n}{n!}=
\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{A^{2k}t^{2k}}{(2k)!} + 
\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{A^{2k+1}t^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}
$$
now, reduce each sum, noting the Taylor series for sin and cos.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
We can use [Pauli Matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) such that $\ds{{\sf A}t \equiv a + \vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}$ and
$\ds{\expo{{\sf A}t}=\expo{a + \vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}=\expo{a}\expo{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}}$. Since $\ds{\pars{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}^{2}=\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}}$, we'll have:

> \begin{align}
> \expo{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}&=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
> {\pars{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}^{n} \over n!}\ =\
> \overbrace{\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
> {\pars{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}}^{n} \over \pars{2n}!}}
> ^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\cosh\pars{\root{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}}}}}}\ +\
> \overbrace{\bracks{\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
> {\pars{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}}^{n} \over \pars{2n + 1}!}}}
> ^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\sinh\pars{\root{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}}} \over \root{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}}}}}
> \ \vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}
> \\[5mm]&=\cosh\pars{\root{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}}}
> +{\sinh\pars{\root{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}}} \over \root{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}}}\,
> \vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}
> \end{align}

In the present case:
\begin{align}
{\sf A}t&=\pars{\begin{array}{rr}0 & 1 \\ -w^{2} & 0\end{array}}t
={1 - w^{2} \over 2}\pars{\begin{array}{rr}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}}t
+{1 + w^{2} \over 2}\,\ic\pars{\begin{array}{rr}0 & -\ic \\ \ic & 0\end{array}}t
\\[5mm]&={1 - w^{2} \over 2}\,t\sigma_{x} +{1 + w^{2} \over 2}\,\ic t\sigma_{y}
=0 + \pars{{1 - w^{2} \over 2}\,t,{1 + w^{2} \over 2}\,\ic t,0}\cdot
      \pars{\sigma_{x},\sigma_{y},\sigma_{z}}
\\[5mm]&\imp\ \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
a & = & 0
\\[2mm]
\vec{b} & = &
{1 - w^{2} \over 2}\,t\,\hat{x} + {1 + w^{2} \over 2}\,\ic t\,\hat{y}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
and
$\ds{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}=
     {\pars{1 - w^{2}}^{2} \over 4}\,t^{2}
-{\pars{1 + w^{2}}^{2} \over 4}\, t^{2}=-w^{2}t^{2}}.\quad$
$\boxed{\ds{{\tt\mbox{Note that}}\
\color{#c00000}{{\sf A}t = \vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}}}$.

> Then,
>   \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\expo{{\sf A}t}}
> =\expo{0}\bracks{\cosh\pars{\verts{wt}\ic}
> +{\sinh\pars{\verts{wt}\ic} \over \verts{wt}\ic}\,\vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}
> =\cos\pars{wt} + {\sin\pars{wt} \over wt}\,{\sf A}t
> \\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\cos\pars{wt} + {\sin\pars{wt} \over w}\,{\sf A}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

here is another way to verify $X = e^{At} = I \cos(\omega t)  + \frac{1}{\omega} \sin( \omega t) \ A$
by showing that $e^{At}$ is the unique solution to the initial value problem $\frac{dX}{dt} = AX$ and $X = I$ at $t = 0.$

we will use the fact $A^2 = -\omega^2 I.$

$\frac{dX}{dt} - AX= -\omega \sin(\omega t) I + \cos( \omega t) A - A[I\cos(\omega t t) + \frac{1}{\omega} \sin(\omega t)A] = -\frac{1}{\omega} \sin(\omega t)[A^2 + \omega^2 I] = 0.$ this establishes the result.